# How To Extract content from pfd file using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js

Hello i am trying different ways to extract content from a pdf file but nothing works for me , like pdf.js when i try using pdf.js it also show error and i dont know why . I am trying this approach

```
var loadingTask = window.pdfjsLib.getDocument('dummy.pdf');
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
 console.log(pdf)
});
```

But it is showing an error **Can not read property of undefine getDocument**.
Please Guys Help Me Extracting content from pdf using pdf.js or anything possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you import it correctly.

```js
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.worker.min.js";

var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("dummy.pdf");
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
 console.log(pdf);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

In React it should be something like this:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjsLib.version}/pdf.worker.min.js`;

const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("dummy.pdf");
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log(pdf);
});
```